# How can I give a custom file names to a code file in ideone.com?

Tags: c++

I am using `ideone` as online `c++` compiler. When I save a code, ideone gives a random name such as

> lnzr40

which might be confusing later on (when I want to open a specific code). I want to change that name or give a custom name at the time of writing/saving the code. How can I do that?

Edit: Labeling or creating custom links may be slightly useful but they are not what I need exactly! I need to modify the file name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am no *ideone* power-user, but there does not seem to be any simple way to change the name of a source code file.

However, there is a note field immediately to the right of the file name in the list of files. You could use this field to enter the appropriate file name:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a case where a link-only answer is appropriate ;)

http://tinyurl.com/Yes-it-is-possible

Comment: The link opens http://ideone.com/lnzr40 which is basically the example code that I mentioned. I could not see a name change. Did I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: @erolyeniaras: Yes, the fact that an URL shortener like TinyURL allows you to generate a nice custom URL for that arbitrary ideone URL.